ddjvu: Does it really support converting to PDF?
ddjvu (DjVuLibre), 3.5.28:
ddjvu --help

returns
-format=FMT       Select output format: pbm,pgm,ppm,pnm,rle,tiff.

Note that it doesn't mention PDF. But then, why does the folowing command works and converts input DjVu file to output PDF one?
ddjvu -format=pdf -quality=85 input.djvu output.pdf


Haven't tried it myself, but command line option description getting forgotten when adding a feature: Happens to the best programmers (and, me, too).
When reality and a short description string clash, obviously, reality is right! So, what's the real question here?

Since you get valid PDF output, it seems that ddjvu does indeed support PDF output, even though its --help description doesn’t list that format (which is still the case in the development repository).
In fact, man ddjvu does list PDF as an output format. Looking at the source code shows that, as long as ddjvu is built with a recent enough version of libtiff (“recent” meaning newer than November 11, 2004), it will support PDF output.
It’s likely that the omission of pdf from the ddjvu --help output is just an oversight.

Yes, it is even mentioned in man ddjvu: The recognized file formats are pbm, pgm, ppm, pnm, rle, tiff, and pdf."
